# NGINX + PHP-FPM issues with burst requests

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, high-load, queue

I have NGINX setup with PHP7.2-FPM and am having issues with burst requests.
The average amount of active processes (fpm children) is 15.

I have these settings (48 core server):

```
listen.backlog = 1024
pm.max_children = 1024
pm.start_servers = 16
pm.min_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_spare_servers = 16
pm.max_requests = 5000
```

I also tested a min. amount of spare servers of 256 which lowered but did not resolve the amount of `Resource temporarily unavailable`. Obviously this is not a setting for production and was merely done to see if this many workers could deal with the size of bursts.

I also tried a listen.backlog of 65536 which didn't make a difference.

What is the way to go? If it would queue the requests there not be any issues.

Edit: I just noticed that fpm-status always reports `max listen queue` as 0

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What is the _context_? Please paste your error logs.

Comment: The error is included ;) `Resource temporarily unavailable`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by increasing the systems `net.core.somaxconn`. The fpm-status seems to be broken in the regards to `max listen queue`, it always displays 0.